# Correct usage of python map with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list of colors, either red or green for plotting. The criteria for this list is that if the input value is less than 0 i return red, otherwise green. I have created a function and I would like to use .map (or lambda), but I am not sure of the exact implementation. I have tried the following:

```
def get_color(value):
    green, red = sns.color_palette()[2:4]
    if value >= 0: return green
    return red
```

My input list of values to evaluate is as follows:

```
delta_loss
[0.0206, 0.0011, 0.052, 0.026, -0.0058, -0.0008, 0.0013]
```

When I try to use .map i get the following error:

```
colors = delta_loss.map(getcolor)

'list' object has no attribute 'map'
```

What would be the correct and most efficient way of achieving my objective in this case?

Comment: `map` is a *function*, not a method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) builtin function if you want a generator, or a list comprehension if you want a list.

If you want to use a list, then as per [@jonrsharpe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64035718/correct-usage-of-python-map-with-a-list/64035728#comment113236234_64035728), it is more idiomatic to use a list comprehension. If you want a generator object, use `map` (you can convert the generator to a list with `list()`).

```
def get_color(value):
    green, red = sns.color_palette()[2:4]
    if value >= 0: 
        return green
    return red

delta_loss = [0.0206, 0.0011, 0.052, 0.026, -0.0058, -0.0008, 0.0013]

[get_color(j) for j in delta_loss]

# Equivalent: list(map(get_color, delta_loss))
```

```
[(0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313),
 (0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313),
 (0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313),
 (0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313),
 (0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392),
 (0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392),
 (0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313)]
```

Comment: FYI that will give a map object, not a list, which may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: FYI 2 if they do want a list a list comprehension is more idiomatic than `list(map(...))`, per e.g. https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe - I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you this is really well explained

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a `javascript` syntax written in `python`.

Why not use list comprehension ?

`[getcolor(x) for x in delta_loss]`

Comment: Thank you this is very nice

Answer (score 1):

As Uri pointed out, your `map` syntax is currently a javascript syntax.
In Python, the `map` builtin funciton is not a method bound to the lists, by which I mean you can't use the dot notation to access it. Simply call `map` and as the first argument, it receives the callback function (which could be a lambda function) and the 2nd argument is the iterable (list,etc.) to pass to the callback:

`map( lambda x: 'green'  if x>0 else 'red', [1,-4,3])`

replace `'green'` and `'red'` with `sns.color_palette()[2]` amd `sns.color_palette()[3]` respectively, and I think you got what you need.

Note that I'm using a "ternary" operator to do a "if ..else" type statement in a single line so I can use a simple lambda function. You can't use a normal if-else statement in lambda functions.

Comment: One last point for those not familiar with ```map``` function, it returns a ```map``` object, which you should be able to use it just as if it was a simple list in most places. But if you explicitly want a list, simply pass it to ```list``` function (```list(  map(....))```) in order  to get a list.